# How can I optimize this incredibly slow left outer join sqlite query?

Tags: sql, sqlite, optimization, left-join, outer-join

I've run into an issue with a SQL query that is basically slow to the point that it takes about 17+ minutes.  I'm pretty sure this is simply due to the fact that the outer join(s) and pure volume of data make this query terrible.  Unfortunately I'm not seeing a great way to rewrite it to get what I want

I've got the following tables (omitting some columns for brevity):

```
Events
ID (AUTOINCREMENT INTEGER PRIMARY KEY) | Guid (16 Byte BLOB) | Time (FLOAT)


Relationships
ID (AUTOINCREMENT INTEGER PRIMARY KEY) | Parent (INTEGER) | Child (INTEGER) | ParentTable (INTEGER) | ChildTable (INTEGER)
```

The Event table has about 25k rows (this will likely quadruple with *real* data).
The Relationship table has about 212k rows (again, will likely quadruple).

Essentially, Event can have nested Events.  The resulting tree has no depth limit (though it's not terribly deep at the moment).

When selecting Event records, my goal is to return rows of data that give me the following data:

```
ID | Guid | Time | ParentIndex | ParentGuid
```

I also fully expect that root level Events will have null ParentID and ParentGuid columns (which was one of the reasons I took the outer join approach).

My query (without constraints) looks like this:

```
SELECT E.*, R.Parent as 'ParentIndex', PE.Guid AS 'ParentGuid' FROM Events AS E
LEFT OUTER JOIN Relationships AS R ON R.Child = E.ID AND R.ChildTable = 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN Events AS PE ON R.Parent = PE.ID ORDER BY E.Time;
```

If I constrain this query with a WHERE clause that filters most of the Events returned, I get a row of data that is exactly what I want.  However, without a tight constraint the execution time is crippling.

I assume there is a better way to write this query to get the same sort of result row, but my Sql-fu has failed me.

Comment: You are returning gobs of data with no conditions.  Perhaps the time is just because of the volume of data.  What do you really want, if not all the data?

Comment: If the where clause gives you what you want, why don't you put it in your query?

Comment: Have you tried looking at SQL EXPLAIN on the query to see what indexes it is utilizing, if any?

Comment: The Events are essentially used for visualization.  If I constrain the query too much with a WHERE clause I lose so much granularity in the result set that there's not much to visualize.  It's far easier in the client code to been visualized data when the ID and Guid of the parent event are known.  Conversely,  I could just do much selects to get the data, but I believe that would result in at least 2 selects for every Event row, which would be a bit harsh.

Comment: @JohnMcMahon:  I've never used EXPLAIN before, I'll look into this now.  I have however tried indexing the Relationships table on multiple columns to try and see if that would help (especially as the data is essentially static once added).

Comment: @JohnMcMahon: Wow the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN statement made it apparent that the index on Relationships.Child wasn't being used.  I created a new index on that column and the query is now instant.  You should add your response as an answer so you get the rep you deserve for that. Thank you!

Comment: @Daniel Have you tried a 2 column index on Relationships? An index on Child and ChildTable might be useful. Also perhaps an Events index for both Parent and Time, which may optimize the ORDER BY clause if it can use an index where Time is already in the order needed.

Comment: @JohnMcMahon: I will certainly play with those in the next queries I will be writing, I'll likely need some more indexing to get the analytics I want with any sort of speed.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Analyze the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) to see which indexes are being used, if any.

Comment: Wow the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN statement made it apparent that the index on Relationships.Child wasn't being used. I created a new index on that column and the query is now instant. Thank you!